# How to separate javascript so it is not inline but as a separate snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have some code that works perfectly within the html editor within WordPress.  The problem is that when switching to the visual editor it strips out the javascript.  I am a novice when it comes to code, and wondering if someone can help separate the javascript so I can add it as a separate script to the wordpress page.

```
<div class="couponactivate">
    <div class="coupon1">
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
        <p>This is our Standard Coupon which gives 10% off</p>
    </div>
    <div class="activatebutton">
        <div style="position:relative;"><a onclick="jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide()" target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow">DOJU</a>
            <div onclick="window.open('http://www.test.com');jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide()" id="jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1" class="couponrevealcoupon">REVEAL COUPON</div>
        </div>
        <div class="expiry">Expires 31 July 2014</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show, What have you tried? Community is here to help, Not do work for you.

Comment: Will do shortly.  I'll have to reconstruct my attempt at solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Really you should add a `class` or `ID` to `.activatebutton > div > div` but if you want to keep the markup unchanged:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.activatebutton').on('click',function() {
            jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide();
        });

        jQuery('.activatebutton > div > div').on('click',function() {
            window.open('http://www.test.com');
            jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you want to do is bind to `onclick` from outside the HTML, rather than in the element itself.  So instead of this:

```
<a onclick="jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide()" target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow">DOJU</a>
```

You might have something like this:

```
<a id="someLink" target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow">DOJU</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#someLink').click(function () {
        jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide();
    });
</script>
```

That `script` block can be put elsewhere on the page, or the script can be put into a separate file and a `script` block can just reference that file.

Note that this is a very simplified example just to demonstrate the idea of binding to an element's event from outside the element.  There are lots of things to consider, and I imagine you'll find those things and learn them with practice.  For example, since the page is parsed in order then that script will need to be placed *after* the link tag in order for it to work.  If it's before the link tag, then you'd need to wrap it in the document's `ready` event to wait for the tags to load before trying to bind to their events.  Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#someLink').click(function () {
            jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
<a id="someLink" target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow">DOJU</a>
```

If tags change over time (such as being added/removed dynamically) then there would be even more to consider in terms of binding to their events.  But at its simplest, using jQuery (since you're already using it), you just identify the element and use something like the `click()` function on that jQuery-identified element (or set of elements) to bind to that event.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new and the question is easy I will help you. Next time you have to try first.

myscript.js:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".activatebutton a").on("click", function() {
        jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide();
    });

    jQuery("#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1").on("click", function() {
        window.open('http://www.test.com');
        jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide();
    });
}
```

put this in head tag (after jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

the rest of html:

```
<div class="couponactivate"><div class="coupon1">
<h3>Subtitle</h3>
<p>This is our Standard Coupon which gives 10% off</p>
</div><div class="activatebutton"><div style="position:relative;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow">DOJU</a><div id="jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1" class="couponrevealcoupon" >REVEAL COUPON</div></div>
<div class="expiry">Expires 31 July 2014</div>           
</div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html  >
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="globe/script/jquery.js"></script>

    <title>
    Html5 All in One
    </title>
    </head>

    <body >
    <div class="couponactivate">
    <div class="coupon1">
    <h3>Subtitle</h3>
    <p>This is our Standard Coupon which gives 10% off</p>
    </div>
    <div class="activatebutton">
    <div style="position:relative;"><a  target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com" rel="nofollow">DOJU</a>
    <div  id="jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1" class="couponrevealcoupon">REVEAL COUPON</div>
    </div>
    <div class="expiry">Expires 31 July 2014</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(".activatebutton a").click(function(){

    jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide()
    })

    $("#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1").click(function(){

    window.open('http://www.test.com');jQuery('#jcorgcr-clean-jcorgcoupon-coupon1').hide()
    })


    })
    </script>   
    </body>
    </html>
```